How can i pick which row is selected when using OR in Mysql
I have a table in MySQL that holds rows of days from 1 to 7 (Monday to Sunday), i want to get a full week of rows to 1 to 7 based on a specific date the date is null in some rows and set in some rows:



id
day
date




1
1
NULL


2
2
NULL


3
3
NULL


4
4
NULL


5
5
NULL


6
6
NULL


7
7
NULL


8
3
2024-05-29



i would like to select the week and it should include the specific date so for example selecting the week based on 2024-05-29 should give me this result:



id
day
date




1
1
NULL


2
2
NULL


8
3
2024-05-29


4
4
NULL


5
5
NULL


6
6
NULL


7
7
NULL



and if a select a date that doesn't exist like 2024-05-05 it should give me:



id
day
date




1
1
NULL


2
2
NULL


3
3
NULL


4
4
NULL


5
5
NULL


6
6
NULL


7
7
NULL



is this possible to do with a single query? otherwise how would you go about doing something like this? thank you
edit: im on Mysql version 8.0

What version of mysql are you on?

Mysql version 8.0

If there are more than date (with a valid date) in a week would you select only 1 but expect to get back 2?

Here is the query that i came up with which does work exactly how i wanted it, if anyone has any remarks on how to optimize this or any other solution i would love to hear it:
SELECT s1.* FROM my_table as s1 INNER JOIN ( SELECT day, MAX(date) as date_max FROM my_table WHERE my_table.date = '2024-06-29' OR my_table.date is null GROUP BY my_table.day ) as s2 ON s1.day = s2.day AND ( s1.date = s2.date_max or ( s1.date IS NULL AND s2.date_max IS NULL ) ) ORDER BY day ASC


Please format your query across multiple lines to make it easier to read. You can clean up your join criteria by using <=> (NULL-safe equal).

Given your sample data plus



id
day
date




9
5
2024-05-31



You could retrieve the whole NULL date week and use that to LEFT JOIN based on the date passed in:
SELECT
    COALESCE(t2.id, t1.id) AS id,
    t1.day,
    t2.date
FROM my_table t1
LEFT JOIN my_table t2 ON t1.day = t2.day AND t2.date = '2024-05-29'
WHERE t1.date IS NULL;

Outputs:



id
day
date




1
1
null


2
2
null


8
3
2024-05-29


4
4
null


5
5
null


6
6
null


7
7
null



Here's a db<>fiddle.
This query will benefit from an index on (date, day).
If you want to return all matching dates for the week of the date passed in, as suggested by P.Salmon in the comments, you could do:
SELECT
    COALESCE(t2.id, t1.id) AS id,
    t1.day,
    t2.date
FROM (
    SELECT id, day, '2024-05-29' - INTERVAL (WEEKDAY('2024-05-29') + 1 - t.day) DAY AS date
    FROM my_table t
    WHERE t.date IS NULL
) AS t1
LEFT JOIN my_table t2 ON t1.day = t2.day AND t1.date = t2.date;

Outputs:



id
day
date




1
1
null


2
2
null


8
3
2024-05-29


4
4
null


9
5
2024-05-31


6
6
null


7
7
null



Here's another db<>fiddle.

Group by day, use a conditional to return NULL when the date column doesn't match the given date, otherwise the date column. Then use MAX() to prefer that row.
SELECT day, MAX(IF(WEEKDAY('2024-05-29')+1 = day, date, NULL)) AS date
FROM dates
GROUP BY day;

SELECT day, MAX(IF(WEEKDAY('2024-05-05')+1 = day, date, NULL)) AS date
FROM dates
GROUP BY day;

